# WebOperationContext behavior for non REST WCF Services?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, soap

What happens in my service method if I use a WebOperationContext, when the endpoint is not REST?

Justification: I have a service that I'm exposing as both REST and SOAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do this - the `WebOperationContext` is intimately bound to the REST stuff.

You can use the regular `OperationContext` in your SOAP service method, if you want to inspect stuff. Does that have the necessary information for you??